# How to manage permissions for S3 mounting in Databricks

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions, mount, databricks

In Databricks, reading from S3 is typically done by first mounting the S3 bucket to the DBFS with:

```
// Replace with your values
//
// NOTE: Set the access to this notebook appropriately to protect the security of your keys.
// Or you can delete this cell after you run the mount command below once successfully.

val AccessKey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
val SecretKey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
val EncodedSecretKey = SecretKey.replace("/", "%2F")
val AwsBucketName = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_S3_BUCKET"
val MountName = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_MOUNT_NAME"

dbutils.fs.mount(s"s3a://$AccessKey:$EncodedSecretKey@$AwsBucketName", s"/mnt/$MountName")
```

Once you mount an S3 bucket, it is available for **all users**. This may cause serious issues where users change or delete data they are not familiar with.

I'd like to mount a few buckets in read-only mode, and not let anyone mound buckets without specific permissions.

How can you manage the permissions for users to mount S3 buckets into Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

This is best accomplished using AWS IAM roles to provide read-only access to buckets. The basic steps are:

1. Create the IAM role.
2. Specify those users that have permission to assume the role.
3. Create a bucket policy that provides read-only access for the role.
4. Mount the bucket to the Databricks file system using the dbfs.fs.mount command.
5. Specify the IAM role when you create the Databricks cluster.

Comment: Could you show us how to do the mount part using a role? The examples I have seen all use ACCESS_KEY/ SECRET_KEY.  
For step 5, could we do that dynamically? 
Thanks!

Comment: and for step 3, what permissions do you need? I think I tried "s3:GetObject" and "s3:ListBucket" but that was not enough